# Filtering Vertices by Edge-Attribut in ArangoDB

Tags: filter, graph-databases, arangodb, aql, nosql

I'm new to ArangoDB and try to do a spatio-temporal DB. For the vertex "Parz1", I have two GeoJSON connected. My goal is to filter the geometry Vertex, which has the Value "9999" for the key "Ende" in its Edge. I couldn't find something in the documentation on how to filter vertices by the value of the edge. Thanks for the help!

The first Vertex:

```
  Document: Parzelle/Parz1
    _rev:83054176547
    _key:Parz1
    {
      "Nummer": "1",
      "Gmd": "Muttenz"
    }
```

The geometry Vertices:

```
    Document: Geometrie/Geom1
    _rev:83050703139
    _key:Geom1
    {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            600000,
            200000
          ],
          [
            600000,
            200002
          ],
          [
            600002,
            200002
          ],
          [
            600002,
            200000
          ],
          [
            600000,
            200000
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
Document: Geometrie/Geom4
_rev:83051424035
_key:Geom4
{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        600000,
        200000
      ],
      [
        599998,
        200000
      ],
      [
        600000,
        200002
      ],
      [
        600002,
        200002
      ],
      [
        600002,
        200000
      ],
      [
        600000,
        200000
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

And the Edges:

```
Edge: hatGeom/37050525987
_rev:83056470307
_key:37050525987
_from:Parzelle/Parz1
_to:Geometrie/Geom1
{
  "Start": "1950",
  "Ende": "2010"
}

Edge: hatGeom/37067237667
_rev:83056797987
_key:37067237667
_from:Parzelle/Parz1
_to:Geometrie/Geom4
{
  "Start": "2011",
  "Ende": "9999"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ArangoDB 2.8 we're offering a new [Traversal and pattern matching api](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphTraversals.html); You then can effectively filter by edges and vertices:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 
  1..3 OUTBOUND 'vertexCollection/startVertex'
  GRAPH 'geometryGraph' 
    FILTER p.edges[1].start > 1950 RETURN v
```

You may even want to use the [Geo index](https://docs.arangodb.com/IndexHandling/Geo.html) to find a start match for the graph traversal:

```
FOR startVertex IN WITHIN(vertexCollection, @latitude, @longitude, @limit) 
  FOR v, e, p IN 
    1..3 OUTBOUND startVertex
    GRAPH 'geometryGraph' 
      FILTER p.edges[1].start > 1950 RETURN v
```

Comment: I've added [a sample for this](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AqlExamples/CombiningGraphTraversals.html). It requires the [modified example generator](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arangodb/arangodb/devel/js/common/modules/org/arangodb/graph-examples/example-graph.js)